# How to disable scrolling in smartphone and tablet browsers?

Tags: jquery, iphone, scroll, smartphone

I use the following  code to disable scrolling in desktop browsers but it doesn't work for iPhone screen resolution.

```
$("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

What else do I need to add?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
//target the entire page, and listen for touch events
$('html, body').on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){ 
     //prevent native touch activity like scrolling
     e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

if having the touch event blocked doesn't work for you, you can always go like this:

```
html, body{
     max-width:100%;
     max-height:100%;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your jQuery code worked nicely for what I was trying to do.

Comment: You have to remove the touchstart because with it you disable also the "click touch" event

Comment: @MarcoMantovani that was not a requirement.

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna provide an a piece that doesn't utilize jQuery so the next "Javascripter" can just copy'n'paste:

```
var defaultPrevent=function(e){e.preventDefault();}
document.body.parentElement.addEventListener("touchstart", defaultPrevent);
document.body.parentElement.addEventListener("touchmove" , defaultPrevent);
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", defaultPrevent);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove" , defaultPrevent);
```

Comment: Just tested this on Android. `defaultPreventDefault()` doesn't seem to exist, but `preventDefault()` does work.

Comment: so much for copy pasta. It's a typo. And corrected now thanks.